# Microsoft Project not opening

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, ms-project

I have a client who is asking me to fix an issue they are having with Microsoft Project.

The issue is that they are attempting to open a task list on SharePoint Online via the 'Open with Project' button in the ribbon, but after the alert asking them if they would like to open it in Project 2016 pops up nothing happens.

I have set up a fresh SharePoint environment and tried it at my end, but I get the same problem. There is no error message (as an alert or in the console) and I have wracked my brain and come up dry.

What I have tried:

- New SharePoint instance.
- Fresh Microsoft Project install.
- Looked at the site/site collection features
- Multiple browsers (specifically Chrome, IE and Firefox)

The issue is the same no matter what I do.
Has anyone else come across this problem before and, if so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 2016 Click-to-run (C2R) or MSI version? Can you share the build number from winproj.exe?

If you are on C2R version, can you try making the following registry edits (save the following as a .reg file and run it) and see if it helps?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentEcs\Overrides]
"ofhdegpklv1irq0"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentEcs\Overrides]
"ofhdegpklv1irq0"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I have actually got in contact with a Microsoft representative and he has informed me that this is an issue on their end that they are aware of and attempting to fix. Thank you for your help though!